# In my Jupyter Notebook, I keep getting new numbers despite using the same random seed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter

I'm testing how various forms of pre-processing can affect the accuracy of my model. I've written the following piece of code that's essentially a function that returns accuracy level of a model.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

def get_acc(data, target):
    # Splits the data randomly
    data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(
        data, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=3)
    classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

    # Calls the function to train the data then creates predictions
    model = classifier.fit(data_train, target_train)
    targets_predicted = model.predict(data_test)

    # Print percentage correctly guessed
    error = 1.0 - np.mean( target_test != targets_predicted )
    # print(error)
    return error

iris = load_iris()
print(get_acc(iris.data, iris.target))
print(get_acc(iris.data, iris.target))
```

The problem is that I'm feeding the exact same data set twice and yet I get different accuracy outputs:

Output:

```
0.9555555555555556
0.9111111111111111
```

What gives? I expect them to be the same because I've set `random_state=3` in my `train_test_split` function. In other words, I think I am using the same seed. Since they are returning different accuracy levels, I'm assuming that my model is being fed different split data each time. I would like the split data to be the same both times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()` has a random state too, try passing it a seed like `random_state=3` as well. All of its arguments can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)

Comment: Yep! That was the problem! That makes a lot of sense now, thanks!